# How to draw different lines with different colours using tikz l-systems

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make a picture of an infinite rooted ternary tree, the following code will do the job quite nicely.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{3-ary rooted tree}{
            \rule{L -> L [s+ [-L] [M] [+R]]}
            \rule{M -> M [s  [-L] [M] [+R]]}
            \rule{R -> R [s- [-L] [M] [+R]]}

            \symbol{L}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
            \symbol{M}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
            \symbol{R}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
            \symbol{s}{\pgflsystemstep =0.4 \pgflsystemstep}
        }
        \draw[rotate = -90] l-system [l-system={3-ary rooted tree,axiom = [-L] [M] [+R], angle=45, step=6cm, order=5}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I would like to have the edges corresponding to each letter to be coloured with different colours, say L red, M green and G blue. I tried

```
  \symbol{L}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}[red]
  \symbol{M}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}[green]
  \symbol{R}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}[blue]
```

but it does not seem to do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your code doesn't works for me. Could you repair it?

Comment: @Ignasi yep, my bad - I was careless with copy/paste. This one should work.

Comment: I'm fairly new to this - is there some "magic" trick to make my code compile and display the result in my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after some thoughts, I think the easiest way is to draw the R,M,L parts separately in different colours. So I split `3-ary rooted tree` into a `R`, a `M` and a `L` part, each one drawing only one of the three "parts" and using `\pgflsystemmoveforward` instead of `\pgflsystemdrawforward` on the other two. Then you can use 3 different `\draw` commands with 3 different colours `:)`.
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{3-ary rooted tree-L}{  %define the left branch
            \rule{L -> L [s+ [-L] [M] [+R]]}
            \rule{M -> M [s  [-L] [M] [+R]]}
            \rule{R -> R [s- [-L] [M] [+R]]}

            \symbol{L}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}  % draw the L branch
            \symbol{M}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}  % only move
            \symbol{R}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}  % only move
            \symbol{s}{\pgflsystemstep =0.4 \pgflsystemstep}
        }
        \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{3-ary rooted tree-M}{ % define the middle branch
            \rule{L -> L [s+ [-L] [M] [+R]]}
            \rule{M -> M [s  [-L] [M] [+R]]}
            \rule{R -> R [s- [-L] [M] [+R]]}

            \symbol{L}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}  % only move
            \symbol{M}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}  % draw the M branch
            \symbol{R}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}  % only move
            \symbol{s}{\pgflsystemstep =0.4 \pgflsystemstep}
        }
        \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{3-ary rooted tree-R}{ % define the right branch
            \rule{L -> L [s+ [-L] [M] [+R]]}
            \rule{M -> M [s  [-L] [M] [+R]]}
            \rule{R -> R [s- [-L] [M] [+R]]}

            \symbol{L}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}  % only move
            \symbol{M}{\pgflsystemmoveforward}  % only move
            \symbol{R}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}  % draw the R branch
            \symbol{s}{\pgflsystemstep =0.4 \pgflsystemstep}
        }
        \draw[rotate = -90,color=blue] l-system [l-system={3-ary rooted tree-L,axiom = [-L] [M] [+R], angle=45, step=6cm, order=5}];
        \draw[rotate = -90,color=red] l-system [l-system={3-ary rooted tree-M,axiom = [-L] [M] [+R], angle=45, step=6cm, order=5}];
        \draw[rotate = -90,color=green] l-system [l-system={3-ary rooted tree-R,axiom = [-L] [M] [+R], angle=45, step=6cm, order=5}];

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**: I found a trick (bug? feature?) to declare the tree only once: the output is exactly the same as above. The trick is you can use the `\symbol` command to just move in the 3 directions without drawing, and tell it to draw in one of the three, and it will override the previous "just move" command for that direction. Give it a parameter and you have it dynamically draw the branch you want!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\newcommand{\defbranch}[1]{
    \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{3-ary rooted tree#1}{  % dynamic definition of the branches
        \rule{L -> L [s+ [-L] [M] [+R]]}
        \rule{M -> M [s  [-L] [M] [+R]]}
        \rule{R -> R [s- [-L] [M] [+R]]}

        \symbol{L}{\pgflsystemmoveforward} % only move
        \symbol{M}{\pgflsystemmoveforward} % only move
        \symbol{R}{\pgflsystemmoveforward} % only move
        \symbol{#1}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}  % draw the branch (overrides previous command)
        \symbol{s}{\pgflsystemstep =0.4 \pgflsystemstep}
    }
}
\defbranch{L} % define the branches (needed only once per documents)
\defbranch{M}
\defbranch{R}

\newcommand{\branch}[2]{  %define command to draw branches.
    %You can add more parameters for step, angle, order,... if needed
    \draw[rotate = -90,color=#2] l-system [l-system={3-ary rooted tree#1,axiom = [-L] [M] [+R], angle=45, step=6cm, order=5}];
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \branch{L}{blue}
        \branch{M}{red}
        \branch{R}{green}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks really good, thanks! The only disadvantage is that if I want to modify the way tree is drawn I have to modify the code in three places.

Comment: @MichalFerov I found a way `:)` please see my edited reply for a way to define the tree only once. If you have any questions feel free to ask!